# Why does this message appear when I run this code?

Tags: c#

I wrote this code which sends an Image between sender and receiver.

First you must run receiver then run sender.

When I test this code on images between 1KB and 1.5KB, it works fine, but when I try to send a larger image, this message appears

> cannot evaluate expression because a
>   native ..........

My code is below, can someone help?

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Drawing.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Threading;

    namespace UPDTester
    {
        public class UDPClass
        {

            public Image Merge(Queue<byte[]> myList)
            {
                int ImgHeight = BitConverter.ToInt32(myList.Dequeue(), 0);
                int ImgWidth = BitConverter.ToInt32(myList.Dequeue(), 0);

                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ImgWidth, ImgHeight);
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

                int x, y = 0;
                while (myList.Count > 0)
                {
                    x = BitConverter.ToInt32(myList.Dequeue(), 0);
                    y = BitConverter.ToInt32(myList.Dequeue(), 0);
                    g.DrawImage(ByteToBitmapConverter(myList.Dequeue()), x, y);
                }
                return bmp;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Image Segmentatoin.
            /// img: the image that we like to divided.
            /// </summary>
            public Queue<byte[]> Segmentation(Bitmap img)
            {
                Queue<byte[]> ByteArray = new Queue<byte[]>();

                ByteArray.Enqueue(BitConverter.GetBytes(img.Width));
                ByteArray.Enqueue(BitConverter.GetBytes(img.Height));                    

                Image temimg;

                for (ushort x = 0; x < img.Width - 5; x += 5)
                {
                    for (ushort y = 0; y < img.Height - 5; y += 5)
                    {
                        //temimg = null;
                        temimg = img.Clone(new Rectangle(x, y,  5,  5), PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                        ByteArray.Enqueue(BitConverter.GetBytes(x));
                        ByteArray.Enqueue(BitConverter.GetBytes(y));                    
                        ByteArray.Enqueue(ImageToByteConverter(temimg));
                    }
                }
                return ByteArray;
            }

            //Sender
            public void SenderUDP(Bitmap img)
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[1024];            
                IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9050);

                Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

                string welcome = "Hello, are you there?";
                data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(welcome);

                server.SendTo(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, ipep);

                IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                EndPoint Remote = (EndPoint)sender;

                data = new byte[1024];
                int recv = server.ReceiveFrom(data, ref Remote);

                MessageBox.Show("Message received from");
                MessageBox.Show(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv));

                Queue<byte[]> temlist = Segmentation(img);
                data = new byte[1024];
                data =temlist.Dequeue();
                //Send Width of image.
                server.SendTo(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, ipep);

                data = new byte[1024];
                data = temlist.Dequeue();
                //Send Height of image.
                server.SendTo(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, ipep);

                data = BitConverter.GetBytes(temlist.Count);
                //Send Count of all list.
                server.SendTo(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, ipep);
                MessageBox.Show(temlist.Count.ToString() + " Iam Sender");

                while (temlist.Count > 0)
                {
                    server.SendTo(temlist.Dequeue(), Remote);
                    //MessageBox.Show(temlist.Count.ToString() + "S");
                }
                //server.Close();
            }

            //Receiver..(IP, PortNum)
            public Image ReceiverUDP()
            //public void ReceiverUDP(ref PictureBox pic)
            {
                int recv;
                byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);

                Socket newsock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

                newsock.Bind(ipep);
                MessageBox.Show("Waiting for a client....");
                //Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a client....");

                IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                EndPoint Remote = (EndPoint)(sender);

                recv = newsock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref Remote);

                MessageBox.Show("Message received from ", Remote.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv));
                //Console.WriteLine("Message received from {0}:", Remote.ToString());
                //Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv));

                string welcome = "Welcome to my test server";
                data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(welcome);
                newsock.SendTo(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, Remote);

                Queue<byte[]> TempList = new Queue<byte[]>();

                //Receive Width of image.
                newsock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref Remote);
                TempList.Enqueue(data);

                //Receive Height of image.
                newsock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref Remote);
                TempList.Enqueue(data);

                //reccive Count of the list.
                newsock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref Remote);
                int count = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
                MessageBox.Show(count.ToString() + " Iam Receiver");

                data = new byte[1024];
                while (count > 0)
                {                
                    data = new byte[1024];

                    newsock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref Remote);
                    TempList.Enqueue(data);
                    data = new byte[1024];

                    newsock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref Remote);
                    TempList.Enqueue(data);
                    data = new byte[1024];

                    newsock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref Remote);
                    TempList.Enqueue(data);

                    MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());    
                    count -= 3;
                }


                return Merge(TempList);
            }

            private byte[] ImageToByteConverter(Image img)
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }

            private Image ByteToBitmapConverter(byte[] buffer)
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
                Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
                return img;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would definitely help if you provided the WHOLE message you are asking about.

Comment: Please post the entire error message you are receiving.  Also, indicate at what line the error is occuring on.

Comment: This doesn't explain your error, but one problem you're going to have is that you'll lose some pixels if the image isn't a multiple of 5 pixels in width/height.

Comment: No message is appear but my program Not response. When you press puss, it will stop in (newsock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref Remote);)
)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the reason it locks up is because UDP doesn't guarantee delivery. Packets can be dropped. If that happens, your receive loop is going to sit there waiting forever for a packet that won't ever come.